# Blank Activity in Android when running the project

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity in android and When i run it on my device the activity starts but its just a blank black page. there are no error messages

the on Create method is as follows

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_re);

}
```

What could possibly be the issue here ?

my manifest

https://codeshare.io/GbQbkA

activity layout :

https://codeshare.io/arODJq

Comment: share layout of MainActivity?

Comment: here is a link https://codeshare.io/arODJq

Comment: @Xemega check my below ans

Answer (score 1):

> Remove this  Your this **`>`** sign  from`layout` there s Extra **`>`** in Your code **after** **`tools:context="com.example.controllcenter.Sokan.AddRE">`**

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFA726"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.controllcenter.Sokan.AddRE">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/renameET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="#FFF3E0"
            android:elevation="44dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="اسم العقار"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/aptET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#FFF3E0"
            android:elevation="44dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="عدد الشقق"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="177dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/getMapButton"
                android:layout_width="170dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#FFA733"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/buttonicon"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="اختيار  الموقع من الخريطة" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:topRightRadius="2dp" />

            />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/getMapButton"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="9dp"

                android:background="#FFF3E0"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="304dp">


            </RelativeLayout>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/latitue"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/address"
                android:layout_below="@+id/address"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="#FFF3E0"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/longitude"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/latitue"


                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/latitue"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/address"
                android:background="#FFF3E0"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reagentET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#FFF3E0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="مكتب العقار"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"

            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reagentphoneET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#FFF3E0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="هاتف مكتب العقار"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/grdET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#FFF3E0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint=" اسم الحارس"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"

            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/grdphoneET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#FFF3E0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="هاتف الحارس"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"


            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_x="122dp"
                android:layout_y="17dp"
                android:text="إضافة" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that fixed it..  i must gone blind for working on this project for the last 20 hours..

Comment: @Xemega happy to help you